# Linguistic name for verbs like 'want', 'expect', 'beg', 

Tags: verbs

In linguistics, there is this certain group or class of verbs that can be used as *We <VERB> you to come.*

Verbs like *to expect* and *to want* are in this class:

- We expect you to come.
- We want you to come.

but most verbs aren't:

- *We eat you to come.
- *We type you to come.
- *We grow you to come.

Does anyone know the name for this class of verbs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within theoretical linguistics, these are called Exceptional Case Marking verbs.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECM_verb

"You" is actually the subject of "to come."  In most cases, infinitives can't have subjects, but verbs like "beg" and "expect" allow their infinitive complements to have subjects.

As a side note, I don't believe that "eat" is an ECM verb, but if it was, what would "We eat you to come" mean? You should choose your sentences carefully so that they *could* mean something, because otherwise you might accidentally think something is impossible just because it doesn't make sense. For example:

- I will eat [the tomato growing in the yard].
- *I will eat [the tomato to grow in the yard].

vs.

- I expect [the tomato to grow in the yard].

**Edit:** There is another class of verbs which look sort of like ECM verbs, but have a slightly different structure. These are called Object Control verbs.

- We persuaded you [`PRO` to come].

http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/ch9.html#oc

Comment: Your starred sentence could be grammatical if eating the tomato causes you to grow in the yard :)

Comment: Ah, well that would be a different "to" then.

Comment: I know, I just find the interpretation entertaining!

Comment: And please promise to also mention subject control verbs, like...er... what's that verb again? ;-)